# Rows dataframe by time input variable

Tags: python

```
data = [{"A": 'Red', 'B': '10:00:00'}, {"A": 'Red', 'B': '10:30:00'},
         {"A": 'Blue', 'B': '10:00:00'}, {"A": 'Blue', 'B': '10:30:00'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["B"] = pd.to_datetime(df["B"]).dt.time

x = (input())

df_2 = df.loc[df.B==time(x)]
```

I want:

If I´d enter `x=10,00` then `df_2` should be:

```
      A         B
0   Red  10:00:00
2  Blue  10:00:00
```

Or if I´d enter `x=10,30` then `df_2` should be:

```
      A         B
1   Red  10:30:00
3  Blue  10:30:00
```

But I have problems with `x` format.
I´ve tried:

```
x= int(input())

x= float(input())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.B` is of type `datetime.time`. To match your input with it, you need to convert it to the same type. For example

```
import datetime
x = (input())
xt = datetime.time(*[int(t) for t in x.split(",")])
df_2 = df.loc[df.B==xt]
```